# Overcharging in regenerative braking

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging

Depending on the system used in a electric car there may be a situation were more energy is being regenerated than can be safely used to charge the battery. What happens to this excess energy? Can the motor controller just briefly disconnect the motor and the battery until the rate of energy transfer subsides to a suitable level? I'd imagine the energy has to go somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another the energy must be converted to heat. It can be converted electrically by regenerating it to resistors. If the motor is briefly disconnected, but the vehicle still needs to slow down, conventional friction brakes need to be used,

Answer (score 0):

On many electric hybrid electric vehicles the braking force is both from regeneration and from friction braking. Regeneration is generally used in preference to friction brakes up to the limits imposed by battery state of charge and charging rate.  Beyond that point the friction brakes are blended with regenerative braking to provide the driver commanded braking.

The Tesla models are a bit different in that the brake pedal does not increase regenerative braking it only adds friction braking to the already existing regenerative braking that happens as soon as the throttle pedal is lifted.
This avoids the tricky process of blending the regenerative and friction braking - in many hybrids this can be noticeable and affects the drivers feel of the braking process.

If the tires lose traction the ABS, regenerative and friction brakes have to be coordinated to safely slow down the vehicle - maintaining control of the vehicle is more important than recovering kinetic energy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers..

Regenerative braking is when the motors attached to the wheels are being driven by the inertia of the vehicle and are acting as generators. How much torque those generators create to brake the vehicle is dependent on how much current is drawn from the generator.

The control system draws an amount of current necessary to perform the designed amount of braking required depending on how far the brake pedal is depressed, or when the accelerator pedal is released.

What happens to that current will vary. If the battery needs charging some, or all, may be used by the charger. The rest will either be dissipated into a resistive load and dumped as heat, or used to charge a storage capacitor for retrieval when required.

All these systems also include regular friction braking systems which either work in tandem with the regeneration system or when demand requires, i.e. heavy braking or electrical system malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dump the energy somewhere else. Usually braking resistors, that are switched on/off at a certain voltage level. If the voltage further rises by means of exces regenerative power, then the only way to prevent damage is to disconnect the motor. I guess, by just inhibiting H-bridge transistors won't help since they have freewheeling diodes.